# While loop whilst recording - iPhone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, iphone-sdk-3.0

What I want to do is have a while statement which loops whilst the recorder.recording property value is set to YES.  So, something like:

while (recorder.recording == YES)
{
    // Do something here until the record button is pressed again
    // Stop the recorder from recording and break out of loop
}

Problem I'm currently facing is that the UI becomes completely frozen due to the while loop.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either use an NSTimer to perform the action at a given time interval while the recorder is recording or look into using a separate thread to do your loop work on.

Tight loops like this will block the UI if done on the main thread, because that's where the UI is running.

Comment: I had thought that this was the case, but wasn't 100% sure.  Thanks.